# invert mosfet gate

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

Is there any way to invert the gate voltage of a mosfet. Weird question, but english is not my native language. I mean: Can I turn OFF a mosfet by applying a voltage at the gate?

Comment: How do you have the MOSFET wired up? What do you have connected to it? Please post a schematic.

Comment: Srry, can't do. That is confident. I have my answer, given by hiasnchri, but thank you anyways for trying to help out.

Comment: If you do not tell us what you really want you will quite possibly not get what you really need. No cct of this sort is so confidential that you cannot show people the basic schematice, and voltages. The answer that you THINK answers your question probably doesn't. The answer is correct as stated but it is likely that you do not understand the limitations it imposes. In most cases it will NOT be what yopu want. Inverting the gate drive signal externally will usually be best unless there are very extreme reasons not to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a p-channel enhancement MOSFET. If the gate voltage is the same as the voltage at the source (typically connected to Vcc), the MOSFET blocks. So you have to apply Vcc to the gate to turn it OFF.

You can also use a depletion mode MOSFET (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_and_enhancement_modes). You have to apply either negative or positive voltage depending on the MOSFET type to switch it OFF.

Comment: Thank you very much. So a p-channel is what I'm looking for? Then I will do just that. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't completely confirm that without a schematic. But if it's done right it should be the thing your looking for :)